# matrix multiplication in swift - simd

Tags: swift, matrix, simd

```
let matrix = simd_double4x4([[10.0, 8.0, 7.0, 8.0], [10.0, 9.0, 19.0, 9.0], [8.0, 7.0, 10.0, 8.0], [8.0, 7.0, 10.0, 8.0]])
        
        let rhs = SIMD4<Double>(100.0, 130.0, 120.0, 120.0)
        
        let result = simd_mul(matrix.inverse, rhs)
        
        print(result)
```

this code works for 2x2 and 3x3 matrices to solve the equation. but when it comes the 4x4 matrix I can't get result. and when I enter same values to a website for 4x4 equation solver I get the result but in swift I can not get it and it just prints -> SIMD4(-nan, -nan, -nan, -nan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is correct. It’s impossible to invert that particular matrix of yours, the determinant is zero.

Change the last row into something like `8.0, 7.0, 10.0, 9.0` and retry.

Here’s an output of some online calculator.

[image]